# setExact() don't trigger at time (earlier)

Tags: android

I am using min API 19 and executing in Android 6.0. I have created an alarm with setExact (I want to execute every 5 seconds). For testing it I have just made this (I created it inside a fragment):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) (getActivity().getSystemService(getContext().ALARM_SERVICE));
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, pendingIntent);
```

And it calls:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Test"+SPreferences.getCountedSample(context), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

But when I click button the toast appear 2 or 3 seconds later.

If I change the trigger time from 5000 to 10000 or even 0, it doesn't change time (10 seconds after clicking button (creating the alarm)) to display the Toast message. It always call broadcast 2 or 3 seconds after clicking the button.

Why the trigger doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, pendingIntent);
```

with:

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+5000, pendingIntent);
```

The 2nd parameter to `setExact()` is a time. You chose `RTC_WAKEUP`, so the time is in the time base of the real-time clock. The value of "now" for that clock is `System.currentTimeMillis()`, so 5 seconds from now is `System.currentTimeMillis()+5000`.